# Как удалить элементы в списке?

Tags: jquery, javascript, select

Добрый день.

Как на jquery удалить элементы option в  select-е?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[@Роман Ракзин](/users/5591/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD), какой именно элемент и при каком условии/событии? В принципе, всё сводится к правильному построению селектора, отличительному признаку определенного элемента <option>. Вот, к примеру, [удаляется тот элемент, который выбран](http://jsfiddle.net/ftdvwem9/) (*удаляем по его индексу*):

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    $('option:eq(' + $that.prop('selectedIndex') + ')', $that).remove();
});
```

Или же удаляем option по его значению ([в примере](http://jsfiddle.net/ftdvwem9/1/) - "v3"):

```
$('option[value=v3]').remove();
```